# How to push up / lift a connection one-form from the base manifold to the total space?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I am following [this YouTube lecture by Schuller](https://youtu.be/C93KzJ7-Es4?t=5417) where he finds the appropriate formalism for the quantum mechanics in the physical curved space.

Everything makes sense to me but at the very end I see that we find the pull backed connection one-form on the base manifold.

He says to the end of the lecture that later on we will see how we can find the connection one-form on the total space, the prinicipal bundle, i.e., the frame bundle, level.

This is not shown, however, in the next video.

I wonder how can we calculate the connection one-form on the total space when we only have information about the pulled back of this form on the base manfiold through a section map?

If we have a tanget vector on the base manifold clearly we can push it forward via the section map. But how about when we have defined a form, as we cannot push it forward from the base manifold to the total space via the section map.

Is the following a good way to illustrate in the case of a flat base space how to derive the connection one-form on the total space from the pulled-back connection one-form on the base manifold?

Consider the trivial bundle $\mathbb{R}^2 \times G \to \mathbb{R}^2$, where $G$ is a Lie group, and let $E$ denote the principal G-bundle with fiber $G$. We can think of $E$ as the bundle whose fiber over each point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is just $G$.

Suppose we have a connection one-form $\widetilde \omega$ on the base manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$ that takes values in the Lie algebra of $G$. This connection one-form is given by a one-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose values are elements of the Lie algebra of $G$ at each point.

Now suppose we have a section $s:\mathbb{R}^2 \to E$ of the principal G-bundle $E$. We can think of $s$ as a map that assigns to each point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ an element of $G$. We can also think of $s$ as a map that takes a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and "lifts" it to a point in $E$ by taking the point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and mapping it to the point in the fiber over that point determined by $s$.

To derive the connection one-form on the total space, we want to "lift" the pulled-back connection one-form on the base manifold to $E$. We can do this as follows:

1/ Given a point $p \in E$, we can use the section map $s$ to identify the point $q=s^{-1}(p)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

2/ We can then evaluate the pulled-back connection one-form $\widetilde{\omega} = s^* \omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ at the point $q$. Since $\widetilde{\omega}$ takes values in the Lie algebra of $G$, this evaluation gives us an element of the Lie algebra of $G$.

**3/ We can then "lift" this element to a Lie algebra-valued one-form on $E$ by extending it trivially in the direction transverse to the fiber. Specifically, for any vector $v$ tangent to $E$ at $p$, we can define the value of the lifted connection one-form at $p$ in the direction of $v$ to be the element of the Lie algebra of $G$ we obtained in step 2.**

By repeating this process for all points in $E$, we obtain a connection one-form on $E$ that reduces to $\omega$ when restricted to any fiber of $E$. This connection one-form satisfies all the conditions required of a connection and can be used to define parallel transport and curvature on $E$.

Comment: Do you know the book 'foundations of differential Geometry' by Kobayashi & Nomizu? It is a very good introduction to all the maths behind Riemannian manifolds, fibre, principle and frame bundles.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, any hint to the answr for this question?

Comment: What do you mean by "being invariant under the action of the structure group"? Note that when you pull back by different sections $s_\alpha$ and $s_\beta$, you should get something like $s_\beta^*\omega = g^{-1}(s_\alpha^*\omega) g + g^{-1}dg$, where $s_\beta = g\cdot s_\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you @TedShifrin, well the question is that how to push forward a form via a section to the frame bundle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't push forward forms, of course. Here's the idea: Cover $M$ by open sets $U_\alpha$ over which the frame bundle $P$ is trivial, and let $s_\alpha\colon U_\alpha\to P$ be sections for all $\alpha$. Define the projection $\psi_\alpha\colon P|_{U_\alpha}\to G$ for all $\alpha$.  *Provided* that we have
$$\omega_\beta = g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}\omega_\alpha g_{\alpha\beta} + g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}dg_{\alpha\beta} \quad\text{with } s_\beta=g_{\alpha\beta}\cdot s_\alpha \text{ on } U_\alpha\cap U_\beta,$$
then we define the $\mathfrak g$-valued $1$-form $\omega$ on $P$ by
$$\omega = (\text{Ad}\,\psi_\alpha^{-1})\pi^*\omega_\alpha + \psi_\alpha^*\phi,$$
where $\phi$ is the left-invariant Maurer-Cartan form on $G$.
I leave you to check well-definedness. You can find this all done carefully in Kobayashi-Nomizu (section 1 of Chapter II).

Comment: Great! by  well-definedness do you mean that if we now pull back this g-valued form to the base manifold we can obtain the g-valued one form we started with?

Comment: Well, no, I meant that this formula gives a globally-defined connection form on $P$ (with the usual properties), so that when $U_\alpha$ and $U_\beta$ overlap, the two formulas agree (this is largely the purpose of the transformation law we have to assume in the first place).